# If I declare a" #define DefInt32 unsigned int" , can I use Sizeof(DefInt32) operator on it?

Tags: c

If I declare a macro for unisgned int as below,

```
#define DefInt32 unsigned int
```

Can I use sizeof(DefInt32)?

Comment: Why don't you try it yourself?

Comment: There are plenty of [online compilers available](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916000/online-c-compiler-and-evaluator) if you don't have one local.

Comment: try `cc -E file.c` to see what exactly happens with your `#define`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `sizeof(DefInt32)` will be preprocessed to `sizeof(unsigned int)`.  This is usually 4 (32 bits) as your name implies, but [may not be](https://stackoverflow.com/a/589684/1397061).

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can use `sizeof(DefInt32)`.

`sizeof(DefInt32)` will be same as `sizeof(unsigned int)`.

Aslo you can do:

```
DefInt32 i;
```

Which will be same as:

```
unsigned int i;
```